# First column names is not deleting from my text file

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, text, ini

I am deleting the some names as per my .ini file. There are some names listed in my **.ini file**. And each time when my application process the input file.. it looks for certain keywords from .ini file and if the keyword is found in my input file it deletes the entire line.

But for me what is happening is **when the .ini files finds a key search in my text file && if my key search is in my second column** then only its deleting the line. I would like the key search to look for my first column too in my text file. How can i add this??

Code snippet:

```
public void do_name()
    {
        string old;
        string iniPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\list.ini";
        bool isDeleteSectionFound = false;
        List<string> deleteCodeList = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(iniPath))
        {
            while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (old.Trim().Equals("[DELETE]"))
                {
                    isDeleteSectionFound = true;
                }
                if (isDeleteSectionFound && !old.Trim().Equals("[DELETE]"))
                {
                    deleteCodeList.Add(old.Trim());
                }
            }
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(textBox1.Text))
        {
            while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var st = old.Trim().Split(new char[] { '\t' });
                if (st.Length > 1)
                {
                    var tempCode = st[1].Substring(1, st[1].Length - 2);
                    if (!deleteCodeList.Contains(tempCode))
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(old);
                    }
                }
                else if (st.Length == 1)
                {
                    //old = "\n";
                    sb.AppendLine(old);

                }
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, sb.ToString());
    }
```

My input text file: Here you can see, the first column values are not searched for some reasons. I don't know..

```
  Designator    MAX PN  Footprint   Center-X(mm)    Center-Y(mm)

   "C10"    "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "122.492"   "69.469" 
   "C100"   "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "264.211"   "12.814"
   "C102"   "100-0009"  "1206 - CAPACITOR"  "251.346"   "11.201"

I would like to add C10, C100 and all first column elements to my .ini file
```

My .ini file looks like

```
 [DELETE]
 100-2333
 233-3233
 C10
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your only looking at column "1".  Since arrays are zero indexed this is actually your second column.  Here's an example of how to get columns 1 and 2, replace the code inside your while loop:

```
            var st = old.Trim().Split(new char[] { '\t' });
            bool hasDeleteMatch = false;
            //loop through all the columns starting at 0 and up to 1 (inclusive)
            for (int col = 0; col < st.Length && col<=1; col++) 
            {
                if (st[col].Length>2)
                {
                  var tempCode = st[col].Substring(1, st[col].Length - 2);
                  if (!deleteCodeList.Contains(tempCode))
                  {
                      hasDeleteMatch = true; //we found a match, don't append to the new file
                      break;
                  }
                }
            }
            if (!hasDeleteMatch) sb.AppendLine(old);
```

if you want to expand this to more columns change `col<=1` to a larger number or delete it to search all the columns.

Comment: getting an error :- `Additional information: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.`

Comment: in line `var tempCode = st[col].Substring(1, st[col].Length - 2);`

Comment: I made a slight change, which might work. Without being inside your debugging environment it's a little hard to know why that line was written the way it was in the first place.

Comment: every thing is getting deleted inside the text file now

Comment: now every thing inside the text file is getting deleted..

Answer (score 0):

you are using st[1] instead of st[0].. st is the resulted array of the split function at this line:

```
  var st = old.Trim().Split(new char[] { '\t' });
```

and because arrays indexes are zero based you should use 0 instead of 1

EDIT - based on MikeH answer:

```
            var st = old.Trim().Split(new char[] { '\t' });
            bool hasDeleteMatch = false;
            //loop through all the columns starting at 0 and up to 1 (inclusive)

            var columns = new int[0, 2]; // the columns you want to remove

            for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++) 
            {
                int col = columns[i];

                if (st[col].Length>2)
                {
                  var tempCode = st[col].Substring(1, st[col].Length - 2);
                  if (!deleteCodeList.Contains(tempCode))
                  {
                      hasDeleteMatch = true; //we found a match, don't append to the new file
                      break;
                  }
                }
            }
            if (!hasDeleteMatch) sb.AppendLine(old);
```

Comment: i need to delete the column 2 also.. now my column1 is getting deleted!!!

Answer (score 0):

When i made two different functions for my search line deletion it worked.. But i think this is too length code.. If any body have idea of combining this.. please post the answer..  i will accept it!!

Function : **key search in first column of my text file**

```
 public void do_name1()
    {
        string old;
        string iniPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\list.ini";
        bool isDeleteSectionFound = false;
        List<string> deleteCodeList = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(iniPath))
        {
            while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (old.Trim().Equals("[DELETE]"))
                {
                    isDeleteSectionFound = true;
                }
                if (isDeleteSectionFound && !old.Trim().Equals("[DELETE]"))
                {
                    deleteCodeList.Add(old.Trim());
                }
            }
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(textBox1.Text))
        {
            while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var st = old.Trim().Split(new char[] { '\t' });
                if (st.Length > 1)
                {
                    var tempCode1 = st[0].Substring(1, st[0].Length - 2);
                    if (!deleteCodeList.Contains(tempCode1)) 
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(old);
                    }
                }
                else if (st.Length == 1)
                {
                    //old = "\n";
                    sb.AppendLine(old);

                }
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, sb.ToString());
    }
```

Function: to **delete the searched text from second column.**

```
public void do_name1()
    {
        string old;
        string iniPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\list.ini";
        bool isDeleteSectionFound = false;
        List<string> deleteCodeList = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(iniPath))
        {
            while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (old.Trim().Equals("[DELETE]"))
                {
                    isDeleteSectionFound = true;
                }
                if (isDeleteSectionFound && !old.Trim().Equals("[DELETE]"))
                {
                    deleteCodeList.Add(old.Trim());
                }
            }
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(textBox1.Text))
        {
            while ((old = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var st = old.Trim().Split(new char[] { '\t' });
                if (st.Length > 1)
                {
                    var tempCode = st[1].Substring(1, st[1].Length - 2);
                    if (!deleteCodeList.Contains(tempCode)) 
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(old);
                    }
                }
                else if (st.Length == 1)
                {
                    //old = "\n";
                    sb.AppendLine(old);

                }
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllText(textBox1.Text, sb.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: @MikeH please the answer... but i think this is too length...

Comment: @yackov mandes zaig hello u there... i have posted an answer here